# Secure upload/download design with malicious storage server

Tags: encryption, authentication, cryptography, file-encryption, integrity

Assume we have a malicious storage server (a user-agnostic key-value store, supporting `server.put(key, value)` and `server.get(key)`) that we want to use for per-user based secure file storage. The two interfaces I want to make secure is `client.upload(username, filename, message)` and `client.download(username, filename)`, which communicate with `server.put()` and `server.get()` behind the scene.

Assumptions:

- Each user has his/her private keys securely stored locally, and public keys stored on a secure public key server.
- The malicious server may try to tamper with the uploaded message.
- The malicious server can make a user upload arbitrary files with any name and content it wants.
- The malicious server will not roll back a file, or delete it.
- Filenames and file contents are non-empty.

Requirements:

- The lengths of the filenames and file contents *need not* be confidential (e.g., the malicious server will not make the user upload one out of two files with different lengths, and try to guess which file he/she uploaded).
- The filenames and file contents themselves must be confidential.
- The client must reject any files that have been tampered with, or not uploaded by the specified user. (I.e., integrity and authentication.)

The design I'm thinking about is:

- Key (to be used with storage server) = `encrypt(filename, priv_key_1)`
- Value = `signed(encrypt(message, priv_key_1), priv_key_2)`

Is there any flaw in this design?